# Phonegap + android local storage data retrieval not working?

Tags: android, cordova

In Android 2.2 I'm not able to retrieve the local storage value after the application is forced to close. If you have any suggestions...Please take a look at my code:

```
WebSettings  ws= appView.getSettings();
ws.setDatabasePath("/data/data/com.decodeSoutions.hive/app_database");
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setDatabaseEnabled(true);                                                                                                                       
ws.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

but it seems to work fine in android 2.1 if I use the database path like this

```
ws.setDatabasePath("/data/data/com.decodeSoutions.hive/database");

The problem is the data stored in local storage, but when I force close my app in android 2.2 all local storage data has been lost , but it seems to be retrieve in and remain stored in android 2.1
```

If anyone knows why this happens, please help me out. Thanks.